# Invalid lint error label-has-for in react App

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, eslint

I keep getting this error for the below code even when it already addresses both implicit and explicit labeling.

> Form label must have ALL of the following types of associated control: nesting, id  jsx-a11y/label-has-for

Code:

```
<label
  className={styles['single-select']}
  htmlFor='select-id'
>
  Select Label
  <select
    id='select-id'
    onBlur={() => {}}
    onChange={() => {}}
  >
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Comment: I checked the [documentation of label-has-for](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/label-has-for.md), and it says it's deprecated.

Comment: Did you try with the up-to-date version? Your  code looks fine.